# Times where one must refrain from flatulence?

Tags: tefilla, tefilin, parts-of-the-body, sefer-torah

From my understanding one should refrain from passing gas during the amidah prayer and when wearing tefillin. Are there other times where one is adjured not to flatulate, perhaps when holding a sacred object such as the torah scroll?